# Show the time picker in hh:mm format

Tags: android, date, timepicker

I have to show the time picker in hh:mm format on Click the edit text.So that I had used the below code.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
  e6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
                    Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                    int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
                    mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(AddFlight.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                            e6.setText(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);

                        }
                    }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time
                    mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
                    mTimePicker.show();

            }
        });
```

It is working well and shows the time picker.But my *issue* is,when I select the 04:15 in timepicker, it display 4:15.It doesn't include 0 before 4.I need to show the timepicker in hh:mm format.

Anyone can help me with this.Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just now I had referred this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807226/time-picker-showing-time-like-47-instead-of-0407) and change the single line:

this line

> e6.setText(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);

to

> e6.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", selectedHour,
>   selectedMinute));

Comment: It does work but it is showing this warning "_Implicitly using the default locale is a common source of bugs: Use `String.format(Locale, ...)` instead_"

Answer (score 12):

Just set the text to "%02d:%02d" as follows:

```
e6.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", selectedHour, selectedMinute));
```

Hope so this might help you

Comment: Can you give some explaination ?

Comment: Hello @ThomasRollet and everybody, if you are looking forward for good explanation here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3377719/12265962.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this way...

```
mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(AddFlight.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
        String formattedTime = "";
        String sHour = "00";
        // converting hour to tow digit if its between 0 to 9. (e.g. 7 to 07)
        if(selectedHour < 10)
            sHour = "0"+selectedHour;
        else
            sHour = String.valueOf(selectedHour);


        e6.setText(sHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
    }
}, hour, minute, true);
```

Comment: on clicking the edittext this code doesn't shown the timepicker.

Comment: don't change whole code. just change code in `onTimeSet()` method. Copy code from answer and post in your code..

Answer (score 0):

Just use this method,

```
private String getDD(int num) {
   return num > 9 ? "" + num : "0" + num;
}
```